# CodeIgniter HMVC How Define a SubModule User(User Logged)

Tags: php, codeigniter, git-submodules, hmvc

I'm new in CodeIgniter and HMVC, and trying to make a web application
The Structure I define is as follows

```
-Modules
   -User
      -Controllers
      -Views
      -Models
   -Orders
      -Controllers
      -Views
      -Models
   -Bills
      -Controllers
      -Views
      -Models
   -Payments
      -Controllers
      -Views
      -Models
     ...
```

The structure that I getting is

```
  http://localhost/site/Orders/.. or http://localhost/site/bills/..
```

That I want is a structure depending of the user logged, like this

```
  http://localhost/site/<currentuser>/Orders/
                or
  http://localhost/site/<iduser>/Orders/
```

How do I get this? I have read a lot of information and I dont know how to do it

Comment: Try reading [Hooks](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html). Get current user from session. Maybe 'post_controller_constructor' hook is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think "`http://localhost/site/`" is the base URL of your website.

CodeIgniter routing pattern is as follows :

```
http://localhost/site/ControllerName/MethodName/Parameters/...
```

you want your URL call like this :
`http://localhost/site/iduser/ControllerName/MethodName/Parameters/...`

You can achieve this by using the bellow little hack in CodeIginter Core.

1. Open system/core/router.php in your text editor.
2. Go to Line number 264 .... function _validate_request($segments)
3. Replace $segments[0] with $segments[1] 
        
   **OR**

   Add this code at line 270

   `$x=$segments; 
   $a=1; 
   for($i=0;$i<(count($segments)-1); $i++) 
   { 
   $segments[$i]=$x[$a];
   $a++;
   }`